# How do I modify the value of jQuery countdown for WordPress plugin?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, countdown

I’am working on a countdown WordPress plugin for products offers I have a user form to set the countdown witch contain days labels, hours label, minutes label.  I have a sample named “**classy-countdown**” and this is the [link](https://vox.space/files/jquery/classycountdown/). I want know how do i define the “end” variable to get values inserted by user.

Comment: Suggest you read [ask] then update question with full particulars of how you expect this to work